# Alternative Way to Pass Checkbox Array to $_GET - Besides Square Braces

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, checkbox

I understand that if I use a checkbox value of name[], then I will receive a data array on the server (when using PHP), named 'name[]'. This has worked fine for me, but I'm running into some URL sizes that could cause issues with less robust IE browsers and all the encoded square braces are killing me in this area, easily causing the URL length to be at least 4-6 times longer than what it could possibly be, if another way were available. Is there a reliable method using javascript (jquery syntax even better) to intercept a checkbox forms values and convert them into something like this:

"&checkboxarray=1-23-45-13-67"

I figure that on the other end I can easily explode $_GET['checkboxarray'] into an actual array and go from there as I usually do with matching the selection array against the options array, etc... I just don't know if it's possible or how to create alter the submit process.

Side note, isn't passing "name[]" to a URL non-standards compliant anyways? Every browser I've used auto encodes it, but not Mozilla, however it seems to work fine.

EDIT: I need to create paginated links, which is why I'm using GET, instead of POST. This is also and industrial search, very comprehensive, lots of power user options.

**UPDATE & Answer:** I managed to come up with my own answer. For anyone else who wants to take advantage of $_GET's easy pagination workflow but you need to pass large data arrays and are worried about URL length, here's a simplistic way to compact it all down into one variable with dash separated values:

NOTE: I *HIGHLY* suggest you first make sure any dynamic arrays generated from queries start with 1 rather than 0 if your going to recheck values after submit, here's how, since 0 can be a real pain in the neck to work with in PHP conditional statements:

```
$your_array= array();

array_unshift($your_array,'');
unset($your_array[0]);
```

In your HTML code, set all checkbox input names to "something[]" and underneath this set of inputs, create a hidden input with the name "something", I suggest you make them match, but I suppose you could use another name, just make sure the hidden one is missing the square braces, also set the hidden input value to "":

```
<input type="text" name="something[]" value="1">
 .....
<input type="text" name="something[]" value="20">
<input type="hidden" name="something" value="">
```

Javascript: NOTE, requires jquery... this grabs all the "something[]" input values and forms a dashed array while killing off "something[]" values from being submitted and only submitting "something".

```
$('#submitbutton').click(function(){

      var searchIDs = $('input[name="something[]"]:checked').map(function(){
      return $(this).val();
      }).get(); 

     var IDstring = searchIDs.toString();
     var newvar = IDstring.replace(/,/g, '-');
     $('input[name="something"]').val(newvar);
     $('input[name="something[]"]:checkbox').prop("checked", false);


   });
```

On the server side, simply explode the 'something' value from $_GET.

```
$somethingArray = explode('-',$_GET['something']);
```

There it is! Hope it helps someone in the future make their GET sent arrays more compact. Bonus: Avoids sending unsafe characters in the URL, Mozilla doesn't appear to auto encode square braces, at least not my version of it on Linux Mint ;)

Update:

I just implemented this code on a big country checkbox form with 284 possible selections. With my old code, even using 'c[]' as the name, my character count was around 3100 characters, with the new approach, my character count now rings in at just 1109. Worth the effort.

Comment: Use `method = 'post'` and accept it as `$_POST` over server side..

Comment: I'm creating paginated links, $_POST breaks the user experience too much.

Comment: Length of URL could be of `2000` characters..I guess your length is not going beyond that..What is the issue ?

Comment: I could, I have many multi checkbox options. I setup a js script to kill all values from boxes where all options are turned on (the php script knows what to do when it happens). The issue... if some decides to search 200 countries instead of all of them, boom, huge 2000+ character URL is triggered, as I need to know explicit details to build the query. It's the possibility factor, I'm trying to make the system as bug proof as I can for IE users, everyone else will likely be fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `POST` instead of `GET` method.

`GET` has URL length limitations.

`POST` is useful in passing long data, e.g. an array in your case.

There is a default limit of `POST` method which is `2MB` which is way higher than `GET`. If needed, it can easily be increased in `php.ini` file `post_max_size 10MB`.

Replace `$_GET` with `$_POST` in your script.

Comment: I've explored POST but I'm creating Paginated links, and POST + Pagination seems like a major design headache for the users. It's a pretty large industrial search form :/

Comment: Keeping pagination values in `GET` and other values in `POST` should do the trick. Set action URL of the form with pagination values in it and remaining values will be posted using `POST`. Will this help?

Comment: Whoa, you can post and get the same form? I thought about maybe mixing, but I don't know anything about this, could you please explain this more? Wouldn't this break the paging since the search values aren't in the URL anymore?

Comment: As I understand it, each link in  paged link array basically re triggers the query, but with limit parameters added on to it.

Comment: Can you edit your question and post sample form or code? That might help.

Comment: I found a solution! Thanks anyways!